# Do Auto complete plug-in for jquery comes with out css

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is their any jQuery plug-in for auto complete that allows our own styling?
Every library i see comes with a built in cascading style sheet.

Comment: Can't you just change the built-in CSS yourself?

Comment: Is there any stylesheet that doesn't allow itself to be edited?

Comment: I think the use of a CSS file implies it can be changed anyway you like, think of the included file as a working example.

Comment: +1 to redress the unwarranted markdown by someone else..... and you can alway choose to use a style sheet or not. Remember CSS and JS do not depend on one another, that's the whole point of "separation of concerns"

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. We can edit it. I see that their is lot of css file that comes with Jquery UI download(i see 4 ). I thought that their might me a simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

At http://jqueryui.com/download you can select "no theme", but you will still get an .css that you need to use. That css is used in the javascript code to open, close and interact with the autocomplete menu and text.

It is pretty easy to alter the .css to make it look like you want it to. Try some small changes and reload the page to see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a perfect script for you, but you can download the [Jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/download) library with the "No Theme" option.

In fact, there is a minimalist default theme, but you can easily override it in order to build your own theme.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI Does indeed allows user-based styling. You can simply **change the css file** as if you'd do from scratch. Heck, just write down the class names and create your own...